# How to trigger onPress event of TouchableOpacity?

Tags: javascript, react-native, events, click, touchableopacity

Using jQuery in html:

```js
$("input:button").on("click",function(){alert(1)}).click()
```

It can trigger click event.

I want to do the similar thing to `onPress` event of `TouchableOpacity` in `react-native`.

```js
<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.75} key={id} onPress={() => {onChangeAttribute(key)}}>
    {<Text>{value.name}</Text>}
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I don't know how to do this. I google it but found nothing.
I just want to trigger onPress event in code not by user's tapping.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you tried is not working ? Your syntax is correct

Comment: onPress={() => { this.methodname() }}

Comment: I want to call this onPress event in code, instead of actually touching it through the user.Just like click() method of jQuery.

Comment: The function I really want to call is onPress,not onChangeAttribute(key).

Answer (score 0):

You should make your code like this:

```js
render () {
  <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.75} key={id} onPress={onChangeAttribute(key)}>
    { <Text>{value.name}</Text> }
  </TouchableOpacity>
}
```

Comment: Do you want to trigger onPress eveent without any user touch?

Comment: not yet.There is a bit difficult to remove setState() out of render().And before  deleting arrow function,it worked well.So i'm going to give up your suggestion...